# Question about algorithm analysis to find all combinations of m elements out of n elements

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing an algorithm in Python to find all combinations of m elements out of n elements.

I have seen the commentary but have no comment, so I have trouble interpreting the problem.

The result of the code is (0,1,2,3), (0,1,2,4) ... (3,4,5,6) when n = 7.

But I am ambiguous about the role of picked and to_pick in code.

**code**

```
def pick(n, picked, to_pick):
    if to_pick is 0:
        return print(picked)

    if len(picked) is 0:
        smallest = 0
    else:
        smallest = picked[-1] + 1

    for next in range(smallest, n):
        picked.append(next)
        pick(n, picked, to_pick - 1)
        picked.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = list()
    pick(7, result, 4)
```

Comment: try to make a tree structure , what happens in each iteration, u will understand it better

Answer (score 0):

`picked` is **ordered** result combination chosen at the current moment
`to_pick` is number of elements needed to make full combination

Just imagine intermediate level -  for example, you have `picked=[1,2]`, so `to_pick` is 2 (2 more elements needed), and you can cthe next element from the range `3..7`

Note small logic flaw - if you choose 7 now, you cannot make the next step and get full 4-item combination (just excessive empty calls), so it would be wise to limit upper limit of for-loop by `n - to_pick`